# dynamodb query to select all items that match a set of values

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

In a dynamo table I would like to query by selecting all items where an attributes value matches one of a set of values.  For example my table has a current_status attribute so I would like all items that either have a 'NEW' or 'ASSIGNED' value.
If I apply a GSI to the current_status attribute it looks like I have to do this in two queries?  Or instead do a scan?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not recommend using scan. Use it only when there is no other option and you have fairly small amount of data.

You need use GSIs here. Putting current_status in PK of GSI would result in hot 
 partition issue.

The right solution is to put random number in PK of GSI, ranging from 0..N, where N is number of partitions. And put the status in SK of GSI, along with timestamp or some unique information to keep PK-SK pair unique. So when you want to query based on current_status, execute N queries in parallel with PK ranging from 0..N and SK begins_with current_status. N should be decided based on amount of data you have. If the data on each row is less than 4kb, then this parallel query operation would consume N read units without hot partition issue. Below link provides the details information on this

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-gsi-sharding.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html